# Remove duplicate url structure

Tags: python, parsing, url

I'm writing a crawler and I have a list which contains set of URL's which is similar to

- somesite.com/colection/id/index.php?if=12
- somesite.com/index.php?id=14
- somesite.com/index.php?id=156
- example.com/view.php?image=441
- somesite.com/page.php?id=sas231
- example.com/view.php?ivideo=4
- somesite.com/page.php?id=56
- example.com/view.php?image=1

I want to parse url with have same structure after domain and get the first url, like Burp Suite, It's have a futures which can remove duplicated url(same parameters but different value).

- somesite.com/colection/id/index.php?if=12
- somesite.com/index.php?id=14
- example.com/view.php?image=441
- somesite.com/page.php?id=asa231
- example.com/view.php?ivideo=4

Well as you can see , the pages which are the same but with different query strings have been removed. This is what I want to archive. I tried many regex but not work. Can anyone be kind to help me out with this. Thanks in advance.
P/s: Sorry about my English.

Comment: Please be more specific (where does `somesite.com/page.php?id=asa231` come from for example?) and post your previous attempts (the regex'es you tried).

Comment: Like Burp Suite, It's have a futures which can remove duplicated url(same parameters but different value).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `urlparse` library to split the URLs into pieces, and then extract the parts you need. For example:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('http://somesite.com/page.php?id=sas231')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='somesite.com', path='/page.php', params='', query='id=sas231', fragment='')
```

Documentation for the python3 version of the library is at [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)